# Python requests - Attempt to get presto documentation returns sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get the content of [Presto public documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/logical.html)  for some analysis using Python requests:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/logical.html')
```

This returns the following error:

```
  File "/Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    requests.get('https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/logical.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 71, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 477, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

Tried diagnose using openssl and I found that the site requires Server Name Indication:

```
openssl s_client -connect prestodb.io:443 -servername prestodb.io    // works
openssl s_client -connect prestodb.io:443                            // doesn't work
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735204868176:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:s23_clnt.c:769:
```

I have done a lot of search and did try something else:

I have tried using a custom HTTPAdapter as described [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) to specify the protocol to be TLSv1 but that doesn't help.

I have also tried directly use SSL context and connection objects and set_tlsext_host_name but it doesn't help either.

It seems to me the requirement is to use TLSv1 and SNI. But I'm not able to get that through requests. Could someone please help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exact version of Python 2.7 are you running? If you're below 2.7.9 you need to install `requests` with the `[security]` extra to get SNI support (e.g. `pip install requests[security]`).

Comment: Since you seem to be on OS X: This is also relevant: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022

Comment: @LukasGraf Thanks. I'm running 2.7.10. I tried the security extra but it didn't seem to help. I'll checkout the issue you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: @LukasGraf I was half way through the issue you sent and it solved my problem. Basically I (re)installed openssl and python using homebrew. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could be of some help :) If you could post the steps that worked for you in some more detail as an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: @LukasGraf Will do. Thanks for the help and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lukas Graf and I resolved this based on https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022. What I actually did is to install OpenSSL from Homebrew, then install a new version of Python 2 from Homebrew which will automatically link against the Homebrew-provided OpenSSL:

```
brew install openssl
brew install python
```

Using the newly installed python I'm able to get the presto document page.